# What happens if a file doesn't end exactly at the last byte?

Tags: java, file

For example, if a file is 100 bits, it would be stored as 13 bytes.This means that the first 4 bits of the last byte is the file and the last 4 is not the file (useless data).

So how is this prevented when reading a file using the FileInputStream.read() function in java or similar functions in other programming language?

Comment: I don't think it _is_ prevented. You just read the whole byte.

Comment: What makes you think you can store 1 bit into a file?

Comment: Since a file is a collection of *bytes*, not *bits*, the file will always end at the last byte. Since file sizes are always in bytes, how would you even know the file is 100 bits? The Operating System sure doesn't know, so how would *you* know? And if you did know, then *you* stop processing bits when you get to 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll notice if you ever use assembly, there's no way to actually read a specific bit. The smallest addressable bit of memory is a byte, memory addresses refer to a specific byte in memory. If you ever use a specific bit, in order to access it you have to use bitwise functions like `| & ^` So in this situation, if you store 100 bits in binary, you're actually storing a minimum of 13 bytes, and a few bits just default to 0 so the results are the same.

Comment: So are all files assumed to end exactly at the last byte? If so, does this mean that files are intentionally made to end at the last byte. I understand how this would work with text files as each character is a byte, how would it work with images,music files,ect.

Comment: @ABC123 All files aren't assumed, they literally have to. A boolean for example only requires a bit, but booleans still take up a byte minimum, because that's the smallest unit that you can use. If you want to find the value of an exact bit on your computer, you can't get that bit, you need to get the byte then use the bitwise functions to access it.

Comment: So a boolean will always be stored as 00000000 or 10000000

Comment: Likewise, a pixel in an image is represented as a byte.

Comment: The exact formatting is up the the JVM, and the binary representation is unique to the hard ware. But essentially yes, it's how in something like C they don't have booleans and use something like ints or bytes instead. So you could do something like `private static final int TRUE = 1;` and then store that instead of the boolean.

Comment: @ABC123 That part is incorrect. It's possible a formatting could store a pixel as a byte, but there's no guarantee. For stuff like that it depends on the image format you're using. For example you could store it at 60 bits. Then in order to save space, you could use byte arrays and parse each pixel at a time, so that for transportation and storage you can store it in plain binary

Comment: The "inability to read one bit" from memory depends on your machine. It is possible on VAX, for example - there are instructions to extract bits from and insert bits to memory.

Answer (score 0):

Current file systems mostly store files that are an integral number of bytes, so the issue does not arise.  You cannot write a file that is exactly 100 bits long.  The reason for this is simple: the file metadata holds the length in bytes and not the length in bits.

This is a conscious design choice by the designers of the file system. They presumably chose the design the way they do out of a consideration that there's very little need for files that are an arbitrary number of bits long.

Those cases that do need a file to contain a non-integral number of bytes can (and need to) make their own arrangements.  Perhaps the 100-bit case could insert a header that says, in effect, that only the first 100 bits of the following 13 bytes have useful data.   This would of course need special handling, either in the application or in some library that handled that sort of file data.

---

Comments about bit-lengthed files not being possible because of the size of a boolean, etc., seem to me to miss the point.  Certainly disk storage granularity is not the issue: we can store a "100 byte" file on a device that can only handle units of 256 bytes - all it takes is for the file system to note that the file size is 100, not 256, even though 256 bytes are allocated to the file.  It could equally well track that the size was 100 bits, if that were useful.  And, of course, we'd need I/O syscalls that expressed the transfer length in bits. But that's not hard.  The in-memory buffer would need to be slightly larger, because neither the language nor the OS allocates RAM in arbitrary bit-lengths, but that's not tied tightly to file size.